# cox model forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot, cox

I would like to generate a cox model forest plot for several models in one

```
 fit1 <- coxph(Surv(years, status2) ~ drug , data = pbc2.id)
 fit2 <- coxph(Surv(years, status2) ~ drug + sex, data = pbc2.id)
 fit3 <- coxph(Surv(years, status2) ~ drug + sex + age, data = pbc2.id)
```

this works

```
ggforest(fit1)
```

but this does not

```
ggforest(list(fit1, fit2, fit3))
```

does anyone know how to make a forest plot for coefficients of several models in the same plot? Preferred would be approaches that allow formatting in publication style (plain)

Comment: I don't think this should be called a "forest plot" even if you use the ggforest function to do it.